# Propagating JavaScript events through a tooltip-like div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Here's the jfiddle for what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/fmvmA/

I have two issues that I'm facing with this example; both of which I figure are related to event propagation.  When the mouse enters the container, I'd like to have a div follow the cursor.  When the cursor leaves the container, the following div should disappear.  This seems like it should be simple... but I'm experiencing problems with the div flickering as you move the mouse, my guess is because the mouse is technically leaving the container when the tooltop div appears.

Additionally, I'd like to be able to click anywhere inside of the container and append a copy of the tooltip div to the position that was clicked.  The example is finicky...but if you set the offset so that the tooltip div is no longer overlapping the mouse then you can see it work.

Is there any simple way to achieve my two goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It flickers because it triggers mouseout when the tooltip is shown since the #ghost is outside the container.. Move it inside and it should be all set..

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/fmvmA/5/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="ghost">
    Click to drop me!
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I noticed a bug when having it inside the container that the `#ghost` doesn't hide even moving outside container.. so I added an offset to the `#ghost` so it appears `2px` below the cursor.

**JS:**

```
$('#container').on('mousemove', function(event) {
    $('#ghost').css({
        left: event.pageX - $('#ghost').width() / 2,
        top: ((event.pageY - $('#ghost').height() / 2) + 2) // +2 px is the offset
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  One thing I did notice with your solution is that the ghost div doesn't get hidden when you mouse out of the container.  Additionally, it will allow you to click outside of the container and place a box.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @ThePromoter Did you try my DEMO link? Also see my edit post.

Comment: Yep, that's the link I used when testing out your solution.  If I move my mouse out from the container slowly then the text gets smooshed together which causes the div's height to increase so the mouse is again inside of it.  I definitely see how your solution could work, but is there anyway to make it work while having the mouse pointed directly inside of the ghost?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I was able to implement your solution if I set the width of the ghost to something known...as to avoid the text crunching.  I'll accept your answer, but I'm still curious to see if there's a way to do this while the mouse pointer is inside of the ghost :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo that works, you'll need to adjust the append positioning a bit. I stayed with the method of appending only on click as per original demo

http://jsfiddle.net/fmvmA/4/

Comment: Your solution seems to do the trick...but only if the ghost div is positioned to be off of the mouse.  Is there a workaround to this so that the ghost div essentially passes the click event to the container div to handle or am I just asking for something out of the realm of possibilities? Thanks!

Comment: if you append the ghost to the container first, then mouse will still be hovering the container even with ghost under mouse. Otherwise you trigger the mouseleave of the container. If append first, might need to add a class to it or something at that point...so easy to remove if clcik doesn't happen